# Unable to scroll div on Firefox using a trackpad. Working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

I have a container in `React`, which is scrolled to bottom by default and user can scroll up if he/she wants. Also, we want to show the scrollbar only after the user scrolls, so it is `overflow:hidden` by default, and once the user starts scrolling, we listen to the `wheel` event, and add a class to make it `overflow:auto`, and then the container scrolls.

Now, this behaviour is working fine for `Chrome` but is not working on `Firefox` when then user is trying to scroll up using laptop trackpad.
On `Firefox`, on the first scroll swipe, only the scrollbar appears and the container does not scroll. It scrolls only on scrolling the 2nd time.

Please check the behaviour here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/naman_anand/5qf79cka/33/

Any idea as to why this difference of behaviour in Chrome & Firefox?
any leads will help. Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that firefox (probably ie and edge also) don't recognize trackpad scroll the same way as when you would do it on a mouse

Comment: Also the wheel event is just an working draft mabe it is just not implemented jet in de ff version you have installed

Comment: The wheel event callback is coming fine. I am adding the overflow:auto to the div, in the onWheel callback of react.

Comment: The issue is that in Chrome, after overflow:auto is added, the container scrolls in the same scroll movement on the trackpad. while in in Firefox, it does not. It scrolls up only in the 2nd scroll movement.

Answer (score 1):

try hiding the doing this instead of overflow attribute

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

be sure to change the #element to your container.

Comment: Ah, thats a pretty solution to this problem. Can use scrollbar-width:none; for Firefox. Thanks Trevor.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the scrollbar use -webkit- because it is supported by major browsers (Google Chrome, Safari or newer versions of Opera)

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

-moz- (Firefox):

```css
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

-ms- (Internet Explorer +10):

```css
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```